# How to check the rules on iptables

Tags: iptables

I am new to the iptables completely. I wrote two rules :

```
1-iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp – dport80  -j DROP.
2-iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT .
```

I want to test or check them and I do not know how ?

Also, I am wondering about the meaning of some rules :

```
1-iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.4 -m mac --mac-source 00:50:8D:FD:E6:32 -j ACCEPT
2-iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT . 
3-iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 -j ACCEPT.
4-iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 6881:6890 -j ACCEPT.
```

Thanks,

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo https://www.howtogeek.com/177621/the-beginners-guide-to-iptables-the-linux-firewall/ https://linuxhint.com/iptables-tutorial/

Comment: To test connections you could use telnet (TCP only) or netcat. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-netcat-to-establish-and-test-tcp-and-udp-connections

Answer (score 0):

### Your rules

#### Rule 1: Deny access to any destination port TCP 80.

It can be tested by web browser. Any page having URL=`http://www.some.domain` must be inaccessible. Such URL uses port TCP 80.

But `https://www.some.domain` (note the "s" in http**s**) will be reachable, because it uses the TCP 443 port.

Pure HTTP (not HTTPS) page to be tested: http://httpforever.com/

Universal (HTTP or HTTPS) test page:

- http://www.httpvshttps.com/
- https://www.httpvshttps.com/

You can select HTTP (TCP 80) or HTTPS (TCP 443) protocol by clicking to the HTTP or HTTPS link paced in top right corner of window.

#### Rule 2: Allow incoming connection to interface `eth0`.

Any rules concerning incoming traffic to `eth0` interface which are placed below this one are useless. It can be tested by access from another network node (e.g. PC) to node where IPtables rule is set. The ping, ssh, nc or other commands  can be used according to ports listening on tested machine.

### Meaning of other 4 rules

All of them are ACCEPT  rules, they allow input traffic.

1. Allow connection from IP address 192.168.0.4 **and** (at the same time) from MAC address 00:50:8D:FD:E6:32. Sending node should have these IP and MAC addresses. The rule  e.g. protects against an ARP attack / address spoofing of important network node.
2. Allow connection from IP network 192.168.0.0/24, i.e. from addresses 192.168.0.0 ... 192.168.0.255. Value `/24` is mask length and is equivalent to mask 255.255.255.0
3. Rule is quite the same as rule 2, but network size is expressed by another format. The mask is used instead of the mask length (in bits).
4. Allow incoming TCP traffic to destination ports in interval from 6881 to 6890. The ports are local, they are listening on the same machine where the IPtables rules are set (or they can listen).

Comment: Thanks  a lot you are awesome teacher you make me understand everything. Much appreciate it !